# avoid row split in excel generated using ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am generating excel sheet as output using iReport 5.6.0. But when i get actual output, in which some of the row's get split-ed because of data overflown. It won't happen for all rows/records.

eg. I have customer data, in which i have address field, which may varies for each of the customer.

So wherever i have lengthy address for customer, those records gets split. Means extra character in cell get transfer to next row same column like.
I've set properties for text field as below:

1. Position Type is Float
2. Stretch Type is Relative to Tallest Object
3. Print Repeated Values is true
4. Remove Line When Blank is true
5. Blank When Null is true
6. Stretch With Overflow is false

Comment: Please add some of the things you tried and how it did not yield the desired results.

Comment: i set text field properties as: Position Type=Float, Stretch Type = Relative to tallest object, Print repeated value = checked, Remove Blank line when null = checked.... That's all

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it, not add a load of comments under it.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of googling... finally i found answer...
Along with above setting..just need to add one addition line in xml.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the following property if you don't want the text to be wrapped:

```
property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"
```

You could set the following property to:

```
property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"
```

When you click the cell the data will be shown in full but will only display the contents according to the width set.